# super capacitors for dummies!

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

What is the consensus on using super capacitors to power a 500w electric bike motor?

Cheap and innovative alternative to li-po batteries, or explosion between thighs waiting to happen?

The plan is to create something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgozrScGN8U).

I will use a 24V 500W motor like [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ZY1020-Electric-Motor-24v-500w-Brushed-E-Bike-Scooter-24-Volt-500-Watt-6mm-Chain/192391102611?ssPageName=STRK:MEBIDX:IT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649).

The super capacitors will have a volt meter assigned to them and when they drop to a certain voltage, I will charge them using 2X 12 v batteries and a switch.

I am by no means wise in this area, just trying to find my way to fun with electronics, so any advice from those who know will be very much appreciated.

P.S. I can draw a terrible diagram if anyone is still unclear, but be warned, i have very limited knowledge and so a diagram from me may not be too enlightening!

Comment: This type of question has been asked before.  The usual result is that it isn't worth the expense.  Costs too much for not enough performance. Search the site for supercapacitor questions.  I'm sure you'll find several.

Comment: Supercaps are good for saving braking energy for the next start. For all else, forget it.

Comment: " explosion between thighs waiting to happen?" no worse than a tank of gas, and like all bikes, you are much much more likely to be killed by that car driver that does not see you.

Comment: If you already have 2x 12 volt batteries then why bother with supercaps. Voting to close as unclear borderline ludicrous.

Comment: Maybe if you tow a thousand supercaps behind you in a cart...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cheap and innovative alternative to li-po batteries, or explosion between thighs waiting to happen?

Neither. But I recommend it, it'll be a great way to exercise and keep fit!

It's easy to calculate the range; if you manage to assemble a 100F 24V capacitor, it'll hold 28800 Joules, which will power a 500W motor for nearly a minute (slowing down the whole time; maybe the first 30s will be useful). Assuming its internal resistance is low enough.

Then you get to start pedalling!

Comment: haha thanks for the response, looks like i could be barking up the wrong tree!

Comment: "It's a feature, not a bug"

Answer (score 2):

Do the math.  Look at the energy density by both volume and weight.

Find how much energy you want to store, then compare the size and weight of batteries to capacitors.

The energy stored in a capacitor is:

J = ½ F V<sup>2</sup>

where J is the energy in Joules, F the capacitance in Farads, and V the voltage.

Again, instead of speculating or guessing, do the math.  You'll find that capacitors aren't ready for this role.  Note also that the voltage of a capacitor changes with its state of charge.  That can be dealt with by clever power conversion circuitry, but does add another level of complexity.

There will be some minimum voltage you need to function.  That represents energy left in the capacitor.  For example, if you can use down to ¼ of the full voltage, then you only get to use 94% of the total energy the cap can store.